# How to insert into session row using pdo

Tags: pdo

I am trying to insert into a session row using pdo prepared statements,but i keep getting an insert in the wrong row.This is my insert statement

```
if(!isset($errMSG))
    {            
        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('UPDATE users_table 
                                     SET   
                                         headerimg=:imgH 
                                   WHERE user_id=:uid');
        $stmt->bindParam(':imgH',$headerimg);
        $stmt->bindParam(':uid',$id);
        $user_id=$_SESSION['user_session'];
```

my session is:

```
$user_id=$_SESSION['user_session'];
```

Comment: can you show us your `dbconfig.php`?

Comment: Why your new code is five times bigger than old one?

Comment: because im updating,editing deleting,and adding the image in the new code,im also saving the image to folder,and unlinking it when deleted

Comment: So DON'T update,edit and add the image in the new code. Do ONE task at a time.

Comment: ok.is this why session row is not being inserted into?

Comment: we don't know. this site is not a live debugging service

Comment: i am aware of that,just needed some assistance with the problem i have

Comment: Sessions are completely unrelated to PDO. it doesn't matter which variable you are using with PDO, be it a session or POST or a cookie. If your sessions don't work then ask a question regarding sessions, not PDO.

Comment: Learn to isolate your problems. Writing a mess of code and then sorting it out is not the way to go. Write a small part, make it work and then move to another part.

Comment: ok,will do.Thanks

Comment: i will edit the question then

Comment: For the proper syntax, refer to the linked question.

Comment: there seems to be no solution on any of the links.

Comment: Basically you just need to learn how to use PDO. The routine for the update query is quite simple, just prepare and execute. exactly as it shown in the linked answer. You just have to follow that example

Comment: ive tried the whole day and whole night,still inserting into a random row and not the session row.ive read the link,but it offers no solutions on inserting into a session row.

Comment: Sessions are completely unrelated to PDO. it doesn't matter which variable you are using with PDO, be it a session or POST or a cookie.

Comment: It is interesting that "you tried whole day" and "the linked answer offers no solution" yet **your code in the question is nowhere any similar to the code in the linked answer**

Comment: im still learning.And would really appreciate your help on this..im really confused.Maybe if you could assist me with linking my image table to my user profile table,i wouldnt be going through all this.my code successfuly inserts,deletes and edits an image from  row,but the reason why i have this problem is because someone suggested i use the same table for everything because i dont know how to use foreign keys to access data from another table.

Comment: i solved,all i had to do was set my session,then declare a variable id and equate that to session,then recycle the id and initialize it for update and insert to alter the specific id row.